# Material-UI not styling components when used with NextJS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I'm starting a project using NextJS, Material-UI and Typescript, which is available at https://github.com/lucastonelli/co-learn-it.

I've followed Material-UI guidelines to work with Typescript and SSR as seen on the repository.

The problem is, even following the guidelines styles from SearchField component are never applied and an error message is displayed on console.

[image: Error message]

However, the classes are being loaded normally on the component, as seen on the first line from the console image below.

[image]

I've tried to move the styling code to the component and changing the functions used to style the component, but those didn't work. Any ideas why the styles are not being loaded? JSS is being loaded on the page normally too.

[image]

**Edit**

For some reason, the line below, added to SearchField, solved the problem.

```js
const StyledSearchField = styles(SearchField);

export { StyledSearchField as SearchField };
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the line below, added to SearchField, solved the problem.

```js
const StyledSearchField = styles(SearchField);

export { StyledSearchField as SearchField };
```